# Showing categories in CMS page

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1

I want to show a list of subcategories contained in a category in a CMS page. This subcategories are NOT in navigation menu, but active. They show a BRAND with description and its products.

I am using this code in CMS page admin:

`{{block type="core/template" template="custom/brands-page.phtml" }}`

And my brands-page.phtml template file includes:

`...

$_brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->setStoreId($store_id)
    ->load(37)
    ->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($_brands as $_brand): 
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_brand->getId());
    echo $_cat->getUrl()
    echo $_cat->getImageUrl()
    echo htmlspecialchars($_cat->getName())
    echo htmlspecialchars($_cat->getDescription())

endforeach
...`

This correctly loops through categories included in navigation, but won't take care for those that aren't included.

I see this information is stored in `IncludeInMenu` in the `data` property of the object passed, but I can't figure out how to process the loop to show all childcategories, both included and not included in navigation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this out, I think this answers your question:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21961/how-do-i-show-sub-categories-as-images-for-a-specified-category

Comment: I spy with my little eye an anti-pattern -- load() inside a loop.

Comment: @pronto Right. @FusionDesign provided a nice link with a complete module by @Marius. If someone deals with this, remember not to load() a model inside a loop, use magento collections instead, and filter results with `addAttributeToFilter` and `addAttributeToSelect`. More on this at: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf and Alan Storm's article, as usual: http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections